# s3fs not receiving s3 updates on ECS container

Tags: amazon-ecs, s3fs

I have an ECS container running that is not receiving updates from new files written to the s3 bucket it is mounting.

Meaning, when a new file is written to the S3 bucket, I am unable to see it in the container I am mounting in.

Image:

```
FROM cubejs/cube:v0.29.17

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install s3fs

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["cubejs", "server"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

bucket=muhbucket
[ ! -d /cube/conf/schema ] && mkdir /cube/conf/schema
s3fs ${bucket} /cube/conf/schema -o ecs
echo "Mounted ${bucket} to /cube/conf/schema"

exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s3fs 1.87 and later have a `stat_cache_expire` value of 900 seconds (15 minutes) which can delay updates.  You can reduce this value although it will make operations like `readdir` slower.  s3fs 1.86 and older cached files forever which made multi-client updates impossible.  Some older Linux distributions like Ubuntu 20.04 continue to ship these older s3fs versions so you might accidentally be using these.